# Parse Compound Queries in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have this query

```
var postsExploreQuery = Post.query()
postsExploreQuery!.whereKey("isPrivate", equalTo: false)

var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postsExploreQuery])
query.whereKey("isPublished", equalTo: true)

return query
```

and Xcode shows me error

> Cannot invoke 'orQueryWithSubqueries' with an argument list of type '([PFQuery?])'

what I'am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should get out of the habit of putting `!` after all your optionals. This removes all the safety that optionals are intended to give you. Unless it has been poorly designed, there's a reason the API you are using will return an optional. Unwrap your optional safely using `if let`. This removes the chance that your program will randomly crash in the future and also gives you the chance to handle the error with an else if it makes sense for your program.

```
var postsExploreQuery = Post.query()
if let postsExploreQuery = postsExploreQuery {
    postsExploreQuery.whereKey("isPrivate", equalTo: false)

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postsExploreQuery])
    query.whereKey("isPublished", equalTo: true)

    return query
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that `orQueryWithSubqueries` expects an array of non optionals, so you probably have to write it as:

```
var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postsExploreQuery!])
```

Comment: Encouraging people to pepper their code with `!` after every optional is less than ideal.

Comment: @Lance As a general rule, I completely agree with you, and I usually discourage using either forced unwrapping and implicitly unwrapped. In this case he's already using the forced unwrapping operator at the 2nd line, so I am not encouraging at all - also taking into account that the variable is initialized in the first line.

Comment: And writing `if let {}` is better? This is as bad a java's try and catch.  swift 1.2 seems to really fallen off the unwrapped cliff.

Comment: @GAlexander actually optional binding or optional chaining should be used in **almost** every case when dealing with optionals (with a few exceptions). Not doing so is like using pointers in C without checking if they are NULL, when you know that they can be NULL. You like it or not, that is how Swift is ;-)